# How do I assign a user-supplied argument to a python attribute when that attribute is a class itself

Tags: python, python-2.7

I may be doing all of this completely wrong, but I'm a google taugh python programmer, so there's that.

I have a created a class called "create" that builds an object.  Properties of that object are instances of another class (settings)

```
class setting:
   def __init__(self,name,value,IsRequired):
       self.name=name
       self.IsRequired=IsRequired
      self.value=value

class create:
filter=setting("filter","filter_name",True)   
consumer=setting("consumer","","True")
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name=name


>>>a=create("test")
>>>a.name
'test'
>>> a.filter.IsRequired
True
>>> a.filter.value
'filter_name'
```

This lets me call the complex properties of each of my objects settings individually.  For example, see if a setting (filter) is required for execution by checking a.filter.IsRequired

To adjust the settings, specifically 'value' I am taking input from the user.
I can reference the overall object with a string by using eval.

```
>>>one="a"
>>>eval(one).filter.IsRequired
True
>>>eval(one).filter.value="NewValue"
>>>a.filter.value
'NewValue'
```

Now the issue.  I'm trying to change 'filter' based on user supplied input.

```
var1="a"
var2="filter"
>>> eval(var1).eval(var2).value
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: create instance has no attribute 'eval'
```

How can I assign a user supplied variable to the 'value' of 'filter' in this example?

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by `eval(var1).eval(var2).value` is:

```
getattr(eval(var1), var2).value
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually just got there.  Turns out walking away for a minute was what I needed.

    inner=getattr(eval(var1), var2)
    setattr(var2, "filter","newvalue)

This ended up working

Answer (score 0):

Your weird class style aside (you should read on class inheritance in Python), you should not use `eval()` for pretty much anything (read [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)) - if you need to access a variable by name from the global namespace use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

```
var1 = "a"
a_value = globals()[var1]
```

Second, if you want to access an attribute of an object by name, use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), so:

```
var1 = "a"
var2 = "filter"
a_filter_value = getattr(globals()[var1], var2).value
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll read up on it.  I know eval is dangerous for a number of reasons.  I am being careful not to eval() anything the user supplies.

Comment: @NathanGrosse - Besides being dangerous from the security/stability point of view, `eval()` is also excruciatingly slow. Apart from some very specific edge cases there really is no reason to use `eval()`.